# how to restrict sizegrip should resize vertically or horizontally only?

Tags: qt, qsizepolicy, qsizegrip

I am adding sizegrip(QSizegrip) to verticall bar on bottom-right side it is resizing both horizontally and vertically actually it should allow only vertically , how to do this? Any other solutions are welcome.

image for details

[image]

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to implement your own sizegrip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964145/adding-a-qsizegrip-to-the-corner-of-a-qlabel

Comment: Thanks.. will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Object which one you want to restrict apply these flags based on requirement

```
    setMaximumWidth(Default_width);
    setMaximumHeight(Default_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the event method (or https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent), check for a MouseMove event and accordingly limit the maximum horizontal size of the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for idea.... I limit the maximum horizontal size of vertical bar